# What are the Screen resolution requirements for Windows 8 all apps

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am developing Windows store apps in windows 8. Can any one help me for the details of screen resolution for Tablet, Phone, Desktop. 
  What are the minimum & maximum screen size requirements recommended by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

I think that [this is the article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh780612.aspx) you may be looking for.

The ['snapped' view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465371.aspx) should also be considered separately.

Edit: @jim-oneil corrected me and provided the link to the [correct resolutions for phones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: [phone resolutions are here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974(v=vs.105).aspx) and they are **NOT** the same size as snapped view for a tablet.